# React Hook weird behavior - Need to create a child component to get the expected result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Why do I need to create a child component to get the results from the hook

```
const SearchFormWrapper = () => {
   const inputs = useQueryInputs();
   return <SearchForm inputs={inputs} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
}
```

The above one doesn't work, but if I replace it with

```
const SearchFormWrapper = () => {
   return <SearchFormWrapping />
}

const SearchFormWrapping = () => {
   const inputs = useQueryInputs();
   return <SearchForm inputs={inputs} onSubmit={onSubmit} />
}
```

EUREKA!, everything works as expected.

Any idea why does this thing happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Please provide a minimal, reproducible example using https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Note that adding a link to a live example *in addition* to having code in the question is welcomed, but an [mcve] should at least be posted in the question itself. Additionally, both the expected and actual behavior should be described.